# Other than correlation of events, what is the halting problem about?

Tags: halting-problem

Object B can be in two state 1(stopped), and 2(running) at an arbitrary time t in the future. Object A can be in two states x, and y at t0. However, if A is in state x, B must be in state 2 at t, and if A is in state y, B must be in state 1 at time t.

Thus, you can't have Object A in state x at t0 and B in state 1 at time t. (In other words, the predictor A can't correctly predict that the thing B will have stopped because predicting so will cause the thing B to be running.) This is merely about some correlation and mutual exclusion of events, I don't see this problem as any significant?

Comment: I see a question mark. But what is it you want answered?

Comment: @greybeard Other than correlation of events, what is the halting problem about?

Comment: I also don't understand what the title has to do with the body of the question.  Please don't respond in the comments: instead [edit] the question to make it clearer what you are asking and to explain the question more clearly.  If you want to know what the halting problem is about, there are *lots*  of references; I suggest reading them.  What resources have you read so far?